# Why is my cat suddenly urinating outside of the litter box?

Tags: behavior, cats

We have an 8 year old cat that recently started peeing in one spot in the hallway. During the summer months she spends most of her time outside but during the cold winter she stays inside mostly, could this be causing her some anxiety?

Comment: Make sure you clean the spot really well. There's a cat urine cleaner called Nature's Miracle that works really well. Then cover it up with some lemon/citrus cleaner. Even if the first time was an accident, cats will return to a spot that smells like urine and associate it with a place to pee.

Comment: @MattS. if you use lemon citrus cleaner after Nature's Miracle it can disrupt the ability for Nature's Miracle to work next time.

Comment: Make sure to clean it with something like vinegar.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Huh, I didn't know that. I used to just wipe it down with a [lemon-scented hand wipe](http://www.soap.com/p/wet-ones-antibacterial-hand-and-face-moist-wipes-40-ct-28975?site=CA&utm_source=Google&utm_medium=cpc_S&utm_term=PX-256&utm_campaign=GoogleAW&CAWELAID=1323157736&utm_content=pla&adtype=pla&cagpspn=pla&noappbanner=true) after and it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: @MattS. the chemicals can disrupt the ability of the Enzyme to work.  I believe even vinegar can be a problem.  Read the instructions on the bottle.